# ASP.NET Core 6 + RabbitMQ + SSL

Tags: asp.net-core, openssl, rabbitmq

I am trying to figure out an issue with ASP.NET Core 6 and RabbitMQ communication via SSL/TLS.

When I use the same code for the RabbitMQ communication with the console app, it is working.

When I try to run the same code in ASP.NET Core on the same machine as the VS2022 by F5, it is working also.

But when I run it on the IIS machine it has the error you may find below.

- The certificate is located in the `wwwroot` folder
- The folder has permission "everyone"
- The certificate is a self-signed private

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.HostName = "129001-01";
factory.RequestedHeartbeat = heartbeat;
factory.AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true;
factory.UserName = "";
factory.Password = "";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.AuthMechanisms = new IAuthMechanismFactory[] { new ExternalMechanismFactory() };

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2 ");

// SSL Certification
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
string certificateName = "CART1290213.A000.pfx";
           
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath + certificateName, certificatePassword);
certCollection.Add(certificate);

factory.Ssl.Certs = certCollection;
factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
factory.Ssl.ServerName = "129001-01";
factory.Ssl.Version = SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
factory.Ssl.AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("4 Connection will start");

IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
IModel channel = connection.CreateModel();
```

Exception thrown:

> 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException' in RabbitMQ.Client.dll
> EXCEPTIONRabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
>
> at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(ISSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCH_CREDENTIALS* scc)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCH_CREDENTIALS* secureCredential)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandleSchCredentials(SslStreamCertificateContext certificateContext, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslStreamCertificateContext certificateContext, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslStreamCertificateContext certificateContext, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
> at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
> at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessBlob(Int32 frameSize)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(SslOption opts)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ArrayPool`1 pool, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
> at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
> at AdvancedConnector.MVC.Models.AdvancedConnector.ConnectRabbitMQ() in C:\Bordel\AdvancedConnector.NET\AdvancedConnector.MVC\Models\AdvancedConnector.cs:line 62
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Error: The view 'StartRabbitMq' was not found.
> Searched locations: /Views/Home/StartRabbitMq.cshtml, /Views/Shared/StartRabbitMq.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'StartRabbitMq' was not found.
> The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Home/StartRabbitMq.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/StartRabbitMq.cshtml
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

I changed permissions, tried to change different paths, credentials, different IIS server.

Comment: got same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was at the IIS:
Application pool - Select the correct/created or default pool - advanced settings
// under Proccess Model - Identity  I had to switch to the NetworkService